# Swapping array with alternative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6

In an array take alternate numbers and swap them. Put it again in the place of array again
e.g., arr = [8,7,4,6,9,3,2,1]
newarr=     [8,1,4,3,9,6,2,7]

**The Code which I tried is below one**

```js
let arr = [8, 7, 4, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1];
let data = arr.map((val, index, curr) => {
  if (index == 0) {
    return curr[index];
  } else if (index == 1) {
    return curr[7];
  } else if (index == 2) {
    return curr[index];
  } else if (index == 3) {
    return curr[5];
  } else if (index == 4) {
    return curr[index];
  } else if (index == 5) {
    return curr[3];
  } else if (index == 6) {
    return curr[index];
  } else if (index == 7) {
    return curr[1];
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

This is not the correct way to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Use the `Edit` link under your question to update it, rather than putting code in the comments

Comment: Kindly please check my edited description there I posted my code.

Comment: What is your expected result for a 9-entry array e.g. [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you consider every odd indexed element to be alternate -

```js
let arr = [8, 7, 4, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1];
let lastAlternate = arr.length % 2 == 0 ? arr.length : arr.length - 1;
let data = arr.map((val, index, curr) => {
  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    return curr[index];
  } else {
    return curr[lastAlternate - index];
  }
});

console.log(data);
```